# Is there a limit to the number of concurrent queries the Mongo Reactive Streams JVM driver will execute?

Tags: mongodb, rx-java

**EDIT**: this doesn't seem limited to the Reactive Streams driver. I tried it with the synchronous driver and saw similar behaviour.

I'm trying to run increasingly more Mongo queries concurrently using the Reactive Streams JVM driver, and after not very long (around 16 concurrent queries) the mean time of each query starts to increase such that the concurrency provides no performance gain. For example:

| Concurrent queries | Query time (ms) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 35 |
| 2 | 32 |
| 4 | 32 |
| 8 | 30 |
| 16 | 30 |
| 32 | **43** |
| 64 | **63** |
| 128 | **171** |

Why aren't those numbers in bold still around 30-35 ms?

- The maximum connection pool size is bigger than the number of concurrent queries, and I can see it using connections equal to the concurrency level.
- I'm using `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` so that there should be no bound on threads available to process the responses.
- The database server's maximum connections it will accept is bigger than the number of concurrent queries.
- Data and indexes fit in memory on the database server, and its CPU utilisation is around 4% so it doesn't seem to be limitted there. I've also tried with different database server sizes in terms of cores/threads and it doesn't seem to make an obvious difference.
- I'm warming both the JVM and the connections by doing everything twice and only timing the second time around.

I'm doing roughly this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    <start timer>
    Flowable.fromPublisher(collection.find(query).limit(1))
        .firstElement()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .blockingGet();
    <stop and record timer>
}
executorService.shutdown();
executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
System.out.println(<mean time per query>)
```

where n = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16...

Comment: Check your connection pool size.

Comment: As mentioned, the maximum connection pool size is bigger than the number of concurrent queries, and I can see it using connections equal to the concurrency level. So this appears to be working fine. (It's set to an arbitrary 400 if that makes any difference).

Comment: How is the <mean time per query> calculated? Could you provide a complete example that can be reproduced? I am interested to probe that.